# Can php forward uncompressed gzip html data to nginx and nginx forward it to user front?

Tags: php, curl, web, nginx, gzip

My server side is nginx-1.2.4 + php-5.3.17. I have a php script to fetch another site's content via curl, which gzip isn't enabled. While nginx has gzip on. So the data flow looks like:

```
                  plain/html                plain/html             gzipped
xxx site's html ==============> php(curl) ==============> nginx ============> user's browser
```

But now, I want to enable gzip of php' curl for the sake of speedup a little bit. Then, the procedure:

```
                  gzipped                plain/html             gzipped
xxx site's html ===========> php(curl) ==============> nginx ============> user's browser
```

Because php's curl will automatically uncompress gzipped html to plain html, so when the html is passed to nginx, nginx will do the compression again.

What I am thinking is, can php keeps gzipped data and forward it to nginx, and no need for nginx to compress one more time. The expected procedure looks like:

```
                  gzipped                gzipped            gzipped
xxx site's html ===========> php(curl) ===========> nginx ===========> user's browser
```

Best regards.

Comment: Why do you use php curl for that instead of simple nginx [`proxy_pass`](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass)?

Comment: @VBart Hi, what I'm gonna really do is not that simple, I need to deal with the data retrieved for further use.

Comment: [`proxy_store`](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_store) can store the data for further use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must send the `Accept-Encoding` header with a curl request:

```
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Accept-Encoding: gzip"));
```

and do not set the `CURLOPT_ENCODING` option.

Also, you may be interested in [nginx gunzip module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gunzip_module.html).

Comment: Thank you. I can get the gzipped data now. But after forwarded by nginx, browser shows binary content instead of parsed html :(

Comment: That is because you do not set content-encoding properly. You must add `header("Content-Encoding: gzip");` to your php gzipped response.

Comment: Did I do in the right way? my php script and nginx.conf https://gist.github.com/4081124

Comment: Are you sure that you're not gzipping it twice? The second one can be in php: http://php.net/manual/en/zlib.configuration.php

Comment: **zlib.output_compression** is off by default. It seems to work now. Have to place `header("Content-Encoding: gzip");` before curl_exec(), otherwise some websites like `https://api.twitter.com/` won't work (show raw gzipped data).

Comment: Curious about one point, when nginx receives php's uncompressed gzipped data, will nginx compress it again? I mean nginx will compress the compressed data? Because its Content-Type is really text/html, and nginx compress all text/html by default if turn gzip on. Since the browser shows correct parsed html page, so I wonder is that because nginx can automatically detect such situation, or gzip algorithm is smart, it won't compress some compressed data?

Comment: gzip isn't actually a compression algorithm, it's just a wrapper format around the `deflate` compression. So, gzip doesn't even know about data, and the page will look broken if it was twice gzip wrapped but dewrapped only once. Nginx looks at the headers from your php daemon, and it does not compress if "Content-Encoding: gzip" already present.

Comment: OK, I got it. I feel lacking such kind of knowledge, where should start to learn? Hope you could give me some advice. Thanks, VBart.